# Slurm --cpus-per-task command

Tags: bash, cluster-computing, slurm, sbatch

Hello everyone I'm actually using a soft called **RepeatMasker**, in this pipeline I can run parallelized job via slurm with the command **-pa**

here is a doc about this command :

```
RepeatMasker -h
-pa(rallel) [number]
        The number of sequence batch jobs [50kb minimum] to run in parallel.
        RepeatMasker will fork off this number of parallel jobs, each
        running the search engine specified. For each search engine
        invocation ( where applicable ) a fixed the number of cores/threads
        is used:

          RMBlast     4 cores
To estimate the number of cores a RepeatMasker run will use simply
        multiply the -pa value by the number of cores the particular search
        engine will use.
```

so in a slurm batch script I should add :

```
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=8

RepeatMakser -pa 2, right?
```

since **8/4 =2**

But I wondered if I should also add others **#SBATCH** parameters or if **--cpus-per-task** is sufficient ?

Thanks al ot